# Exception handling for socket exception

Tags: java, exception

I need to do different things based on the kind of exception i catch, the following are the two methods i learnt that can be used:

Method1:

```
 try{
    ..
    ..
    }catch(SocketTimeoutExceptione){
     //do something
    }
    catch(RunTimeException e){
    //do something
    }
```

Method 2:

```
try{
}
catch(RunTimeException e){
if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                 LOGGER.error(e);   

            }else {
                LOGGER.error(e);
                //do something
            }
}
```

I get the following exception which is a known connectivity issue: Exception thrown org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "test": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

The method 1 is not feasibe as it will still enter the runtime exception block.
In method 2 i cannot check if it is a instance of run runtime exception, as socket excpeption is not part of it. 
How do i handle it in this case

Comment: I didn't understand in method 1, once the SocketTimeoutException is caught how it is caught by RunTimeException?

Comment: You are mistaken. Method 1 does not also enter the `RuntimeException` block on a `SocketTimeoutException`. Clearly you haven't even tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.Object
  java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
      java.lang.RuntimeException
        org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException
          org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException
            org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
```

This is the exception class hierarchy. I think if you try to catch `ResourceAccessException` instead of `SocketTimeoutException` it will be okay. But when catch could not find the specific exception, if it can catch its super exception classes, it catches that, in your case it is `RuntimeException`.

Ref : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResourceAccessException.html

Comment: Thank you, that explains why it was not catching socket timeout.